# Exec not working in NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

I am new to NSIS i am trying to execute an executable while installation similar to pre request. I tried the below code which copies the exe to the installation path but it is not executing it.

```
Section "example" example
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  File "setup.exe"
  Exec "$INSTDIR\setup.exe"
  BringToFront
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 8):

The answer from Seki is mostly correct, I'd just like to add that the correct syntax for Exec/ExecWait is **always** `Exec '"c:\path\app.exe" param1 "par am2" param3'`

Parameters are of course optional but the path to the app should always be quoted, not just because in your case where $INSTDIR could contain spaces but at least on Win9x it will fail no matter what if you don't quote (According to the NSIS manual)

If the spaces/lack of quotes is not the issue then there are a couple of other things you might want to look into:

- $OUTDIR is the working directory for the new process (SetOutPath sets this)
- Missing dll's etc (Check with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx))

Comment: Mmmh, thanks for pointing that double-quotes are always mandatory. In the help of the latest release, it is not that obvious as it states at 4.9.1.2 "[...]Note, if the command could have spaces, you *should* put it in quotes to delimit it from parameters.[...]", and also indicates that quotes are mandatory for win9x. Maybe that the help could be updated?

Answer (score 2):

Do the `$INSTDIR` variable maps to a directory whose name contains spaces? If so, you should add simple quotes to include the double quotes into the `Exec`argument :

```
Exec '"$INSTDIR\setup.exe"'
```